# How do I attach sources for Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I started using Kotlin in Android Studio but I would like to inspect the Kotlin sources the same way I can press <kbd>Ctr-B</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd-B</kbd> for "jump to the declaration" to see the source for any standard Java class.

For instance, if I take the default Android Studio Kotlin project and add one line calling the standard Kotlin `listOf()`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    listOf("hello", "goodbye");
}
```

and press <kbd>Ctr-B</kbd> on `listOf()` I only get the following:

```
public fun <T> listOf(vararg elements: T): kotlin.collections.List<T> { /* compiled code */ }
```

If I click on `Choose Sources` I cannot find the source file in the directory that comes up. How do I set up Android Studio to see the source for these standard Kotlin classes?

Answer (score 8):

In the decompiled class file you need to click on `Choose Sources`:

[image: the bytecode file]

You will then get a dialog that looks like this:

[image: runtime jar doesn't have sources]

You will not find the sources in the `kotlin-stdlib` directory. Instead you need to scroll down to `kotlin-stdlib-common`:

[image: sources are in kotlin-stdlib-common]

Where you can choose the sources. The `jump to declaration` command now works as expected:

```
/** Returns a new read-only list of given elements.  The returned list is serializable (JVM). */
public fun <T> listOf(vararg elements: T): List<T> = if (elements.size > 0) elements.asList() else emptyList()

/** Returns an empty read-only list.  The returned list is serializable (JVM). */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> listOf(): List<T> = emptyList()
```