How to debug Kotlin based libraries in Android Studio?
I want to put break points in external libraries in my android project.
As I can see android studio see the implementation code in libraries that has Java code. But in Kotlin I see only the names of methods and classes.
And I see
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

Message.
Besides that at the top I see message
Decompiled .class file, byte code version 52.0(Java8)
So I don't see any implementation logic that I want to debug.
Please direct me how to solve this

Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777155/how-do-i-attach-sources-for-kotlin-in-android-studio help?

@CrazyCoder no that's actually Kotlin lib. But I need external other libs

That would be the same, google how to attach sources to the libraries. In Gradle projects, there is an option to download sources.

Does this answer your question? Intellij IDEA "Decompiled.class file, bytecodeversion:52.0 (Java 8
